# What are some great philosophers of the 20th/21st century, and what are their ideologies?

Tags: modern-philosophy

I am new to philosophy and would like to learn more about it in the future.

I would like to compile a list of influential philosophers of the 20th and 21st century and a brief overview of their corresponding ideologies/works, so I could get in contact with some modern aspects of philosophy. It does not have to be scholars who have serious, multi-volume works published, but can also be lesser known, or even philosophical content creators.

Comment: See [link](https://www.thefamouspeople.com/20th-century-philosophers.php)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It could be interesting to ask which philosophers are most distinctively 21st century - people that were not so much borne of a tradition, but came about in a wholly independent way. To me, sort of what John Cage is to classical music, Walt Whitman somewhat to poetry, and possibly Whitehead’s process philosophy.

Comment: Jean Claude Van Damme comes to mind

Comment: Did you mean to ask 'What are' or did you mean 'Who are'?

Comment: I nominate Noam Chomsky. He knows a lot about many things. And he's an anarchist.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [Heidegger](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/heidegger/).

I barely understand Heidegger, but have frequently had the impression that Heidegger basically created a new field of philosophy altogether. My understanding is that he critiqued Husserlian phenomenology by showing that there were questions and categories even more primary. I have often felt that studying Heidegger forces you to change how you see things, yet without exposure to him, it is unlikely you would rediscover his thought on your own. Also, Heidegger strikes me as a philosopher *par excellence* because he straddled the traditional divide that many philosophers have done, which is that they are not just analysts, but ultimately exist to espouse *useful knowledge* - useful, in a personal sense. *Being and Time* is not just a theoretical tract, but, skimming through it, it appears Heidegger emphasizes the personal ramifications of his understanding of ‘Being’ - thematizes it, existentially. With an artistic flourish, Being and Time does not end on a triumphant, conclusive tone, but after hundreds of pages of theoretical scaffolding, ends on an elusive, open-ended question:

> Something like 'Being' has been disclosed in the understanding-of­-Being which belongs to existent Dasein as a way in which it understands. Being has been disclosed in a preliminary way, though non-conceptually; and this makes it possible for Dasein as existent Being-in-the-world to comport itself *towards entities* - towards those which it encounters within­-the-world as well as towards itself as existent. *How is this disclosive under­standing of Being at all possible for Dasein*? Can this question be answered by going back to the *primordial constitution-of-Being* of that Dasein by which Being is understood? The existential-ontological constitution of Dasein's totality is grounded in temporality. Hence the ecstatical projection of Being must be made possible by some primordial way in which ecstatical temporality temporalizes. How is this mode of the temporalizing of temporality to be Interpreted? Is there a way which leads from primordial *time* to the meaning of *Being*? Does *time* itself manifest itself as the horizon of *Being*?
>
> [PDF](http://pdf-objects.com/files/Heidegger-Martin-Being-and-Time-trans.-Macquarrie-Robinson-Blackwell-1962.pdf)